# Can not return a list from a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm having an issue returning the result of a recursive function with Python.

My function needs to return a list of pairs of possible comparisons between integers in a range of max `list_upper_range`.

It's important that two ints are paired only once each pair.

The function behaves as expected until I print the result, having returned the result to where the function was called.

```
def generate_comparisons_list(list_upper_range, iter_start, list_of_cases):
    if iter_start == list_upper_range:
        #print(list_of_cases) here verified condition was met
        return list_of_cases

    for i in range(iter_start+1, list_upper_range):
        this_case = [iter_start, i]
        list_of_cases.append(this_case)

    iter_start += 1
    generate_comparisons_list(list_upper_range, iter_start, list_of_cases)

list_of_cases_a_and_b = generate_comparisons_list(list_upper_range=6, iter_start=1, list_of_cases=[])

print(list_of_cases_a_and_b) #returns None
```

Result should be returned as

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 5]]
```

Have I misunderstood the way Python handles lists in recursive functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python functions don't automatically return the last statement (the way ruby does), you have to do a

`return generate_comparisons_list(list_upper_range, iter_start, list_of_cases)`

at the end of your function.

Have a look [here](https://repl.it/C5M4) to see it working.

Comment: This worked legend! But it won't let my mark as correct just yet. Thanks

Comment: This is sort of outside the scope of your question, but here is also a more consise way of generating what you want with itertools. `[x for x in itertools.product(range(1,6), range(1,6)) if x[0]<x[1]]`

Comment: Yes that's a lot nicer

Comment: You can get even simpler: `[[x, y] for x in range(1, 5) for y in range(x+1, 6)]`

Answer (score 1):

Your function `generate_comparisons_list()` is intended to return a list, but in the recursive call, the return value is discarded.  Your need to return the result

```
return generate_comparisons_list(list_upper_range, iter_start, list_of_cases)
```